# GNU APL how do you edit a function

Tags: editor, apl

I'm having troubles figuring out how to edit a function in GNU APL.

I have tried ∇func (DEFN ERROR), )edit (BAD COMMAND), )editor (BAD COMMAND)
and all give me errors.

Any suggestion on how to edit a simple function would be appreciated.

GNU APL 1.8 on Arch Linux
Build Date:     2020-07-07 19:33:16 UTC

Comment: It should be noted that GNU APL targets script based development where interactive editing doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the line editor (a.k.a. the `∇` editor).

[Dyalog's documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Defined%20Functions%20and%20Operators/TradFns/APL%20Line%20Editor.htm) should apply to GNU APL too.

An example session:

```
⍝ define Foo:
∇r←Foo y
 r←2×y
∇

⍝ apply Foo (result to stdout):
Foo 10

⍝ change Foo's line 1:
∇Foo[1]
 r←3×y
∇

⍝ apply new Foo (result to stdout):
Foo 10

⍝ display Foo's definition (to stderr)
∇foo[⎕]∇
```

This should print the following to stdout:

```
20
30
```

And report `Foo`'s new definition to stderr:

```
[0]   r←foo y
[1]   r←3×y
```

Comment: Perfect.  That works like a charm.... I was missing the [1] stuff.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if the execution is suspended because a problem occured ( verify with )si ) you can't edit your function with ∇
You must before execute '→'

Example :
∇aaa
[1] w← ⍳
[2] ∇
aaa
SYNTAX ERROR
aaa[1]  w←⍳
^ ^
)si
aaa[1]

```
  ∇aaa
```

DEFN ERROR+
∇aaa
^

→
)si

∇aaa
[2]